# Problem with MyBase when converting old VB.NET toolbar

Tags: vb.net, add-in

I'm working on a project to convert and older set of ArcGIS tools that were developed for 9.x using VB.NET.  I'm trying to convert them to an Add-In for 10.4.

So far, I have created the Add-In and copied the code from the old project, but I'm getting an error that is preventing me from building the project.  The old project has an ArcGIS class file which refers to MyBase.m_enabled when as part of the hook for accessing the application.  In the new Add-In however, this reference gives a build error with the message:

'm_enabled' is not a member of 'Object'.

The full code for the ArcGIS class is below:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Drawing
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.BaseClasses
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.CATIDs
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Display
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesRaster
Imports System.Windows.Forms

<ComClass(ArcGISClass1.ClassId, ArcGISClass1.InterfaceId, ArcGISClass1.EventsId),
ProgId("IntervisibilityTools.ArcGISClass1")>
Public Class ArcGISClass1

    Private m_application As IApplication

#Region "COM GUIDs"
    ' These  GUIDs provide the COM identity for this class
    ' and its COM interfaces. If you change them, existing
    ' clients will no longer be able to access the class.
    Public Const ClassId As String = "4c9af923-e5db-428c-9626-24bd2403688b"
    Public Const InterfaceId As String = "375cc171-dc44-4ff2-9929-ee4641481847"
    Public Const EventsId As String = "02cf9a2e-0d56-4f11-91f7-649365beb8f7"
#End Region

    ' A creatable COM class must have a Public Sub New()
    ' with no parameters, otherwise, the class will not be
    ' registered in the COM registry and cannot be created
    ' via CreateObject.
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnCreate(ByVal hook As Object)
        If Not hook Is Nothing Then
            m_application = CType(hook, IApplication)

            'Disable if it is not ArcMap
            If TypeOf hook Is IMxApplication Then
                MyBase.m_enabled = True
            Else
                MyBase.m_enabled = False
            End If
        End If   

    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem occurs on the two lines that read "MyBase.m_enabled = True" and "MyBase.m_enabled = False"
What is strange, though, is that all the other command and tools in this project contain the same code set in their OnCreate() methods and they don't trigger the error.

Is there some kind of difference between an older 9.3 project, and a new 10.4 Add-In that would cause this?

Does the project need the ArcGIS Class to access the application?

Comment: It's just "Enabled" as in Enabled = True but you've got more problems than that... all references to hook and COM GUIDs have to go for a start! Try creating a new empty Esriaddin using the VB template and have a look at how it works, there's quite a few subtle differences in the invocation of the tool, so read carefully, but after that your user code should be mostly copy/paste.